# ElasticSearch Scroll API Connection time

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch 6.8 version. I just want to use Scroll API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html) with scroll=1m connection time. (1m is an example, what I am asking is the maximum value for the x minute or hour..)

What I am wondering is this scroll connection time. If I request with the scrollId the connection time resets but what is the maximum time of it or is it bad to keep connection very long ?

I want to use scrollId with 1-10 million of records and export my documents as batches each 1 minute. Anyway, if my system is down somehow, I want to continue where I stopped, so I want to use my conection as long as possible if it does not use extra extra memory or cpu etc.. What is the maximum time that I can keep connection alive and what it should be? Or should it be ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Max value to keep scroll context alive is 24h(24 hours). This limit can be changed by setting the "search.max_keep_alive" cluster setting.

Setting large value can increase the load of the shards.

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html#search-request-scroll)

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for
>   processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the
>   contents of one index into a new index with a different configuration

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context)

> Normally, the background merge process optimizes the index by merging
>   together smaller segments to create new bigger segments, at which time
>   the smaller segments are deleted. This process continues during
>   scrolling, but an open search context prevents the old segments from
>   being deleted while they are still in use. This is how Elasticsearch
>   is able to return the results of the initial search request,
>   regardless of subsequent changes to documents.

From [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html#_clear_scroll_api)

> Search context are automatically removed when the scroll timeout has
>   been exceeded. However keeping scrolls open has a cost, as discussed
>   in the previous section so scrolls should be explicitly cleared as
>   soon as the scroll is not being used anymore using the clear-scroll
>   API: